# how to show dialog in service in angular 2

Tags: angular

imagine we have a server that sometimes tell us show some dialogs for confirmation.
I actually think I have to show dialog from service but in angular doesn't have this ability.
how can implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Angular services are specifically built for sharing the data between different controllers & to implement the generic functions.

The best way is to take response from the server, pass response to the controller & on the basis of response (i.e. true/false) show the dialog.

Reference how to use angular 2 modal:
https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal

Comment: it is good. but imagine we have a lot of response that needs dialog or something like this. it makes a very big duplicate code in our components.

Answer (score 1):

Basically as already said by @pranav Services are used to share data between controller and to perform diff actions,
you must have to send some flag in this case status code (which i assume is proficient) than accordingly you can show some dialog/alert 
or whatever you want to show.

> how to show dialog in service in angular 2

if you still want to show dialog/popup from your service you have to use some third party library, here i am using `toaster` in this,
you can call this toaster from anywhere whether it is from function/button click or form service you juts have to add
js and css file of toaster.
here is working demo of the same

<kbd>[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ezGVD5zMJEh0oQWuYtgl?p=preview)</kbd>

PS: you also can use growl from primeng if you want to call dialog from your controller,  see here

- http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/growl